# Laravel routes error NotFoundHttpException in compiled.php

Tags: php, laravel, wamp, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have my index.php page which works perfectly, but when I want to go on another page, like the "About Us" page, I have the NotFoundHttpException in compiled.php at line 7610.

My routes are like this:

```
Route::get('about', 'AboutController@index');
```

And my Controller is:

```
class AboutController extends Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        return view('template.aboutUs.about');
    }
}
```

I have enable the rewrite module on Wamp.

And I'm  on a Windows 7.

Comment: This is what I did stackoverflow.com/questions/29169503/laravel-5-notfoundhttpexception?noredirect=1

Comment: Re-instal doesn't change anything

Answer (score 3):

You should probably run in your console:

```
php artisan route:clear
```

to clear your cached routes file.

Comment: I just tried, and it doesn't work.
Even after restarting Wamp and clearing the routes again.

Comment: Laravel routes are case sensitive. Do you actually have a `views/template/aboutUs/` folder containing your `about.blade.php` file?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the fallowing virtual directory according to your project
in XAMPP\apache\conf\httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "F:\xampp\htdocs\larvel\col_att\public"
ServerName shah_larvel.dev
</VirtualHost>
```